# How to hide id from url in yii2

Tags: url, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to hide `blog id` from **url**.

For understanding better:

I want this URL

```
mysite/blog/post-slug-<id>  // will be like: mysite/blog/post-slug-358
```

change to

```
mysite/blog/post-slug
```

Here my my URL code:

```
<a href="<?= Url::to(['post/view', 
'id' => $model->id, 'slug' => $model->slug ]) ?>">
```

and this is my *config/main*:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                    'blog/<slug>-<id>' => 'blog/view',
             ]
```

could any one help me to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove  `-<id>` from your url manager:

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'blog/<slug>' => 'blog/view',
         ]
     ]
```

Then in your BlogController in actionView you can get it with this code:

```
$slug = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('slug');
```

I'm not sure that 'class' is nessecary; This i in my project how I use it:

```
   'urlManager' => [
        'baseUrl' => '/',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'ajax/<action>' => 'ajax/<action>',
            '<first_step>/<second_step>/<third_step>' => 'page/index',
            '<first_step>/<second_step>' => 'page/index',
            '<first_step>' => 'page/index',
            '<first_step:.+/>' => 'page/index', // redirect 301 /
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: thank you for answering. if I remove id, how do I have to get in the id to show the blog post?

Comment: Do I have to find the blog post by slug?

Comment: you will have only slug, so YES, you have to find object by slug property.

Comment: but I wanted to find by id, I supposed there is a way to hide id from url and find by id.

Comment: You cannot "hide" it from url. Use it or remove it from url and use the slug. You can search for id by this slug, but it is same logic.. you use post slug

Comment: Yes it's the same logic and also it will take more time to response in front of fin by id. am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but this is the way if you want to remove <id> from your url sllug :) Of course you can set index in DB to your field slug

Comment: yes I have to test test the speed on slug find, so I really thank you for answering

Comment: Also your slug field must be unique in db table. And if you think I answered to your question please vote it is right. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes it must be unique, I will be happy if you vote my question too. thank a lot :)